# CMS made simple modules are installing but not active

Tags: mysql, apache, cmsmadesimple

I am installing modules in CMSMSbut they are greyed out and I can't use them. Tried uninstalling, re-installing to no avail. Thought it was just form builder at first, but then tried the slider, gallery, all the same.

I'm using CMSMS 2.1.3, php 5.5.34, apache mysql 5.5.48.

Don't know what's going on.

thanks, Matt

Answer (score 0):

Check Site Admin > System Information for any identified errors or warnings.

If that doesn't help in the top right of that Admin page click the 'View Text Report' and provide those details here. Will help others give you some more specific advise.

Another thought ... try reinstalling the core in case there was an issue with the files or installation.